# Glut characters display function issue opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am facing a problem in character display on frame like this picture. In this picture a red circle is draw and there are some characters written on it.
[image: Sample 1 image]

My code is working fine except characters display function. I don't know what coordinates i give in these functions like `glRotatef` `glTranslatef` `glScalef` to display the character according to picture.

Here is Code:

```
using namespace std;

float x = 1, y = 1;

void init(void) {

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

}


void drawCircle(float pointX, float pointY, float Radius, int PointsDrawn)
{

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    for (int i = 0; i < PointsDrawn; i++)
    {
        float theta = i * (2.0f * (float)M_PI / PointsDrawn);
        float x = Radius * cos(theta);
        float y = Radius * sin(theta);
        glVertex2f(x + pointX, y + pointY);
    }
    glEnd();
}


  void print(float x, float y, char* text)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glScalef(5,5,2);
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *text);
    glPopMatrix();
}


void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    drawCircle(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.80f, 360);


glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
print(-0.5f, 0.5f, "D");

    glFlush();

}


void reshapeFunc(int width, int height) {
    if (height == 0) {
        height = 1;

    }
    else {
        height = height;
    }


    float aspectRatio = (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height;


    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    glLoadIdentity();

    if (width <= height)
        glOrtho(-x, x, -y / aspectRatio, y / aspectRatio, -1.0, 1.0);
    else
        glOrtho(-x*aspectRatio, x*aspectRatio, -y, y, -1.0, 1.0);
}




int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(590, 590);
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutCreateWindow("Frame");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(&display);
    glutReshapeFunc(&reshapeFunc);
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question is not defined well.I am assuming you want to do like the first picture using your code.

In your code you are drawing both "D" and "E" at the same position and scaling the output.To achieve the final output you have to translate and rotate all the characters a bit. You can do by modifying the current print function a bit.

First change the scalef value of 1/152 to 1/552 inside print. Add a rotatef with an argument. Then call the print function with relevant position and rotation argument.For usage see opengl documentation of the functions.

Edit:

Here is my code:

```
void print(float x, float y, float z,char* text) { 
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glScalef(1/552.0,1/552.0,1);
    glRotatef(z,0,0,1);
    glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *text);
    glPopMatrix();
}


void display()
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    drawCircle(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.80f, 360);
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    char *ch="DEVELOP";
    for (int i = 0; i <7; ++i)
    {
        float rad=M_PI/180;
        double ang=135-15*i;
        double ang_letter=45-15*i;
        print(0.6*cos(ang*rad), 0.6*sin(ang*rad),ang_letter,ch+i);
    }
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: i defined the question clearly i know all these functions Rotatef and scalef but don't know what coordinates i give in this functions

Comment: @JohnDoe you drew the circle with radius .80 . So clearly the range of the translate argument will be -.80 to +.80 . If you want to keep it in upper half y coordinate should be 0 to .8. According to first picture try x with [-.5,+.5] and y with [+.5,+.7].

Comment: i give these coordinates but nothing is display can you do it with code example `glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f) print(-0.5f, 0.5f, "D")`

Comment: @JohnDoe you probably deleted the scalef in the print. That's why you can't see as the letter is too big. Try the scale with 552.

Comment: `void print(float x, float y, char* text)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    
    glTranslatef(x, y, 0);
    glScalef(1/552.0,1/552.0,1);
    glutStrokeCharacter(GLUT_STROKE_ROMAN, *text);
    glPopMatrix();
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104105/discussion-between-john-doe-and-md-momen-bhuiyan).

Comment: but your code for 7 characters but if i add 48 characters than how it fit on one complete rotation